# php str_replace not working...?

Tags: php, str-replace

I've been stuck for hours and honestly, I do not get why... I got a `str_replace` which is absolutely not working for some unknown reasons...

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE['order'];
    $cookie =  str_replace($_POST['rmv'], '', $cookie);
if(preg_match('"/'.$_POST['rmv'].'/"', $cookie))
        echo $cookie;
```

which output `$cookie` value... So it is obviously not working. However, when I enter the `$_POST['rmv']` value inside the `str_replace`... it is working.... ex:

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE['order'];
        $cookie =  str_replace('some very long value here', '', $cookie);
    if(preg_match('/some very long value here/', $cookie))
            echo $cookie;
```

here, the code is working... how can that be?

Let say `$_POST['rmv'] ='dsafsdfsdffdfdss.......';`
First I do `$cookie = str_replace($_POST['rmv'],'',$cookie);`

The logic would be that if $_POST['rmv'] was found inside $cookie, it would be removed, if not then a preg_match would returnfalse... the strange part is that when I run a preg_match on it, it return true, like It found the $_POST['rmv'] inside $cookie but it does not remove it.

Comment: Don't mix up singe and double quotes in your `preg_match()` call.

Comment: Well, when I change the $_POST['rmv'] value with a short string like 'eee', the first code works if(preg_match('"/'.$ee.'/"', $cookie)) where $ee = 'eee'

Comment: Check the value of `$_POST['rmv']`. Also remove double quotes from `preg_match` in first code block

Comment: I did check the value, what I did was echoing $_POST['rmv'] then put the raw value in the str_replace (copy/paste) and for unknown reason, was working. because I do a $cookie = str_replace($_POST['rmv'],'',$cookie) but then when I run a preg_match, the $_POST['rmv'] from the $cookie, it return true...

Comment: `preg_match('/' . preg_quote($_POST['rmv'], '/') . '/')`

Comment: Check my edited comment - remove double quotes.

Comment: thanks, I think i did not elaborate enought, I will edit the question